# YouTube video thumbnails not getting loaded

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, error, youtube

On YouTube webpage, instead of the video thumbnail images, I see only a blue box with a question mark in it. Any video on YouTube does not seems to work either. Can anyone help me? I am not able to find a proper way to solve this error.

Last action performed before encountering the issue: Installing Unity 2018.3 (it is working fine)

I have a mid 2010 13" MacBook Pro running macOS High Sierra 10.13.6

[image]

Comment: Try the following one by one: 1. Open YouTube in a private tab 2. Try clearing browser cache. 3. Try opening YouTube in a different web browser.

Comment: I am a pretty new mac user. How can I clear browser cache? It works if I simply delete history?

Comment: In the Safari menu bar go to Safari → Preferences → Privacy and clear all cookies. Then in Safari menu bar go to Safari → Clear History.... Do note that this will clear all the browser history for all the websites.

Comment: It does not work at all

Comment: First lets see if it is only a Safari issues, install Google Chrome and visit youtube.com and see if the issue persists. If it does check the "App store" for any Safari related updates.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with the icons thumbnails that shows a blue box with a question mark in it. I'm running a Mac Pro mid-2010 running High Sierra.

I finally got it to work after setting the DNS setting to Google DNS.
Apple > System Preferences > Network > Advanced > DNS Tab
And add Google's DNS servers
Click the plus (+) button below DNS Servers table and insert
8.8.8.8
and
8.8.4.4

Click okay and close Safari/Chrome and hopefully it'll be fixed.